# Radius of Convergence of Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

How does one prove that if a function as $n$ poles, and domain the complex plane except the poles, then the radius of convergence of the Laurent series at each pole is the distance to the nearest pole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be your function. If the poles are $z_0,z_1,\ldots,z_n$, consider the Laurent series$$\sum_{n=-N}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n\tag1$$of $f$ about $z_0$, where $N$ is the order of the pole. Assume the no pole of $f$ is closest to $z_0$ than $z_1$. If $(1)$ converges in a region $D(z_0,R)\setminus\{z_0\}$ with $R>\lvert z_1-z_0\rvert$, then $\lim_{z\to z_1}\sum_{n=-N}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$ exists, which is impossible, since $z_1$ is a pole of $f$.

On the other hande, consider $F(z)=(z-z_0)^Nf(z)$. There is a standard Complex Analysis theorem that says that the radius of convergence of theTaylor series of $F$ about $z_0$ is *at least* the distance from $z_0$ to the closest point outside the domain of $f$, that is, $\lvert z_0-z_1\rvert$. Since $f(z)=\frac{F(z)}{(z-z_0)^N}$…